# How can I unit test performance optimisations in C?

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc, jenkins

I've been working on a portable C library that does image processing.

I've invested quite some time on a couple of low level functions so as to take advantage of GCC auto-vectorization (SSE and/or AVX depending on target processor) mode while still preserve a somewhat portable C code (extensions used: `restrict` and `__builtin_assume_aligned`).

Now is time to test the code on windows (MSVC compiler). But before that I'd like to setup some kind of unit testing so as not to shoot myself in the foot and loose all my carefully chosen instructions to preserve GCC auto-vectorization code as-is.

I could simply `#ifdef/#endif` the whole body function, but I am thinking of a more long term solution that would detect upon compiler update(s) of any regression.

I am fairly confident with unit testing (there are tons of good framework out there), but I am a lot less confident with unit-testing of such low level functionality. How does one integrate performance unit testing in CI service such as jenkins ?

PS: I'd like to avoid storing hard-coded timing results based on a particular processor, eg:

```
// start timer:
gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
// call optimized function:
...
// stop timer:
gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
// hard code some magic number:
if( t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec > 42 ) return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

Comment: do you have non-optimized (generic)  functions? It would be better to compare execution time w/ them... meaning that `t_opt` expected to be less than `t_non_opt`... but even that is not a 100% guaranty. Other processes may do random disk access in parallel, your test could be preempted any time... and a bunch of other things may happened not in your tests...

Comment: What are you aiming at?  Do you want to ensure that after your modifications your code remains correct (then you would be doing unit-testing) or do you want to check the performance of the resulting code (which is something different and may be approached in different ways)?  In the latter case, you might even want to print out the generated assembly code to compare it against your expectations.

Comment: @DirkHerrmann that's the whole point ! How do I print 'portable' assembly code ? This may depends on exact gcc version, thanks for additional details if you are familiar with generating assembly code.

Comment: @malat (maybe a bit off, but since you are used to GCC..) why does it have to be MSVC? why can't it be [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) instead? (and therefore GCC *again*? not to mention, that you can write C99 or even better, C11 instead the very old (and limited) C89 which is the only standard MSVC supports as is)

Comment: Have you considered microbenchmarking frameworks like google benchmark or similar??

Answer (score 1):

Your problem basically boils down into two parts:

1. What's the best way to performance benchmark your carefully optimized code?
2. How to compare the results of the comparisons so you can detect if code changes and/or compiler updates have affected the performance of your code

The [google benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark) framework might provide a reasonable approach to problem #1. It is C++, but that wouldn't stop you from calling your C functions up from it.

This library can produce summary reports in various formats, including JSON and good old CSV. You could arrange for these to be stored somewhere per run.

You could then write a simple perl/python/etc script to compare the results of the benchmarks and raise the alarm if they deviate by more than some threshold.

One thing you will have to be careful about is the potential for noise in your results caused by variables such as load on the system performing the test. You didn't say much about the environment you are running the tests in, but if it is (for example) a VM on a host containing other VMs then your test results may be skewed by whatever is going on in the other VMs.

CI frameworks such as Jenkins allow you to script up the actions to be taken when running tests, so it should be relatively easy to integrate this approach into such frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

A way to measure the performance in a simple and repeatable way would be to run a benchmarking unit test through valgrind/callgrind. That will give you a number of metrics: <del>CPU cycles,</del> Instruction and Data read and write transactions (at different cache depths), bus-blocking transactions, etc. You would only have to check those values against a known-good starting value.

Valgrind is repeatable because it emulates the running of the code. It is of course (much) slower than directly running the code, but that makes it independent of system load, etc.

Where Valgrind is not available, as in Windows (though there are mentions of valgrind + wine + Windows programs on Linux), [dynamoRIO](http://www.dynamorio.org) is an option. It provides tools similar to Valgrind, like an instruction counter, and memory and cache usage analyzer. (Also available on Linux and seemingly half-ported to OS X as of this writing)

Comment: not portable on windows, but at least gives much more details than just the test timing.

Comment: There is mention of valgrind+wine setups, but yeah, that might get complicated.

Comment: @malat, if you are still working on this, I just found something that might be the equivalent of valgrind's various tools for Windows: http://dynamorio.org/ (check the "instruction counting tool inscount" and "multi-process online cache simulator drcachesim")