# Unit test that the container uses memcpy optimization

Tags: c++, unit-testing, optimization, copy-constructor

Let's say there is some custom `std::vector`-like container that uses memcpy optimization in it's copy constructor to memcpy trivially constructible objects instead of calling multiple copy constructors.

How can I unit test that the optimization is really applied?

i.e.

```cpp
struct foo { /* some members */ };
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<foo>);

my_vector<foo> v1{ /* some foo objects */ };

my_vector<foo> v2 = v1; // how do I test that single memcpy was called for all foo objects instead of multiple foo copy ctors? or how do I test that none copy ctors were called at all?
```

Comment: You can't. You can only test whether they are eligible for memcpy. Compiler optimizations are not something determined in the c++ language. And adding anything to the copy ctor will cause it to cease being trivially copyable.

Comment: There is a closely related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557041/how-can-i-unit-test-performance-optimisations-in-c

Comment: I believe this isn't a compiler ( or std library ) optimization but a custom data structure optimization. I just want to try to make sure that my container actually uses the optimization correctly

Answer (score 1):

There may be ways of replacing the standard library implementation of `memcpy` with something that saves data about any copying done (see e.g. [How to replace C standard library function ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107259/how-to-replace-c-standard-library-function) ), but in general it would be easiest to pass an additinal template parameter in that contains implementations for the copying:

```
struct default_copier
{
    void memcpy(void* dest, void const* src, size_t size) const noexcept
    {
        std::memcpy(dest, src, size);
    }
};

template<class T, class Copier = default_copier>
class my_vector
{
    [[no_unique_address]] Copier m_copier;

    T m_values [10]{};
public:
    my_vector()
    {
    }

    void fill_first(T const* values, size_t size)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T>)
        {
            m_copier.memcpy(m_values, values, sizeof(T) * size);
        }
        else
        {
            std::copy_n(values, size, m_values);
        }
    }

    Copier& copier()
    {
        return m_copier;
    }

};

struct test_copier
{
    size_t m_memcpyUseCount{ 0 };

    void memcpy(void* dest, void const* src, size_t size)
    {
        std::memcpy(dest, src, size);
        ++m_memcpyUseCount;
    }
};

int main() {
    {
        my_vector<int, test_copier> vectorOfTriviallyCopyable;
        int buffer[2]{};
        vectorOfTriviallyCopyable.fill_first(buffer, std::size(buffer));
        assert(vectorOfTriviallyCopyable.copier().m_memcpyUseCount == 1);
    }

    {
        my_vector<std::string, test_copier> vectorOfNonTriviallyCopyable;
        std::string buffer[2]{};
        vectorOfNonTriviallyCopyable.fill_first(buffer, std::size(buffer));
        assert(vectorOfNonTriviallyCopyable.copier().m_memcpyUseCount == 0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When did we stop trusting the compiler?

Comment: @PaulSanders • I trust the compiler.  I don't trust the monkey-with-a-gun behind the keyboard.

Comment: @Eljay Especially when it's me holding the gun 

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some way to detect there is no copy-construction:

If a custom container is std-like ( which means that it can be parametrized by an allocator ) a mock allocator can be used to observe if any container's element copy-construction is done by observing allocator's `construct` method. And if there are no `construct` method calls you can be pretty sure that no copy construction was done.